# TypeError: fetch failed while making api call in nextjs 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am using fetch in NextJS 13 and whenever I add no-cache option there is a fetch failed error.

This is happeing in my server-side component

Here is my code sample

```
async function getData() {
  const data = await fetch('https://651bf577194f77f2a5af24b0.mockapi.io/products', { cache: 'no-cache' }).then((res) => res.json())
  return data;
}
```

The error I get is as below

```
 Internal error: TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11522:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
digest: "215226357"
```